# How do i evaluate $\int_{|(x,y)|=r} \frac{xy^2}{x^2+y^2} dy$?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

How do i evaluate $\int_{|(x,y)|=r} \frac{xy^2}{x^2+y^2} dy$ ?

By Green's theorem, i have shown that it is equal to $\frac{1}{r^2}\int \int_{B(0,r)} y^2 dxdy$

I don't know what should come next..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Substitute $x(t) =r\cos t , y(t) =r\sin t , 0\leq t\leq 2\pi $ then  we have $$\int_{|(x,y)|=r} \frac{xy^2}{x^2+y^2} dy =\int_{0}^{2\pi } r\cos t \sin^2 t r\cos t dt =r^2 \int_{0}^{2\pi } \frac{1}{4} \sin^2 2t dt =\frac{r^2}{8}\int_{0}^{2\pi } (1-\cos 4t )dt =\frac{\pi r^2}{4} . $$